# Detect multiple words with preg_match in php

Tags: php, preg-match, detect, search-multiple-words

i want detect some words when read first line file.

this my code

```
    $open  = @fopen($file,"r");
    $line  = @fgets($open);
    $close = @fclose($open);
    return preg_match('/\<\?php/',$line);
```

words for detect

```
"<?php","<?","<html>"
```

i do not know how do it with multiple words,
any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.alternation.php - alteration can help you. In your particular case, you have to extend your regexp as the following:

```
return preg_match('/^<(?:\?(?:php)?|html>)/',$line);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this comment well. Are you asking about how to perform the same check in perl? If yes, it would be smth like this:

`perl -e 'my $str="<?php"; if ($str =~ /^<(?:\?(?:php)?|html>)/) {print "Matched!\n"}'`

Comment: Ah, it's pretty simple. We again use the alteration: 
`return preg_match('/^<(?:\?(?:php)?|html>)|#!\/usr\/bin\/perl/',$line)`
Please note that slashes are escaped by backslashes. In order to make the regexp looking simpler, we can use "@" as delimiter for the regexp, as the following: 
`return preg_match('@^<(?:\?(?:php)?|html>)|#!/usr/bin/perl@',$line)`

Comment: oh very thanks to you , yes it very simple :) , i'm learn about preg_match , and today i learned nice pattern from you also